# Default User/Group for File Created By Java

Tags: java, unix, file-permissions

I have a java application that includes a feature to allow users to upload images and associate them with an item in the data model. I noticed recently that the user and group of the uploaded files was no longer correct. I haven't changed any code related to that functionality and this feature was working correctly up until a week or two ago so I'm assuming a setting must have changed somewhere.

What I want to know is, how does java determine the user/group of a newly created file if those settings are not explicitly defined in the code?

FYI the application is a jboss 6 server running in a unix environment.

For more info see also: [Unable to Change File Permissions Even as Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712331/unable-to-change-file-permissions-even-as-root)

Comment: I expect a Java process acts just like all other processes: new files are created with the the effective user and group of the process itself.  Is your file’s owner not the user JBoss is running as?

Comment: How would I determine the user/group that jboss is running as then?

Comment: In Linux, I would use `ps l` (that's a lowercase L).  In other Unix systems it’s probably either the same thing or `ps -l`.